# Why mvc Html.HiddenFor does not render my field?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to do this simple thing

```
<%= Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)%>
```

the model is

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue=true)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

but i always get this rendered

```
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="UserInfo.Id" id="UserInfo_Id">
```

i've check and the id is NOT 0.. ?!

need some explanation here...

Edit

The problem seem's to be the post thing mentionned below.
This is working

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%= Html.AttributeEncode(Model.Id) %>" id="<%= Html.IdFor(model=>model.Id)%>" name="<%= Html.NameFor(model=>model.Id)%>" />
```

Thanks to Manaf

Comment: what happens when you put the same field in a normal `textboxfor`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the case with you but the `Html.HiddenFor()` "do not output correct values after a post if the value is changed during the post." and this is a not a bug it was designed that way.

**Quick Fix :**

Don't use the helper, try this instead :

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%= Html.AttributeEncode(model.Id) %>" id="Id" name="Id" />
```

Always worked for me :)

Comment: in fact we should do this to handle complex model <input type="hidden" value="<%= Html.AttributeEncode(Model.Id) %>" id="<%= Html.IdFor(model=>model.Id)%>" name="<%= Html.NameFor(model=>model.Id)%>" />

Comment: *Apparently* it's not a bug.  Unfortunately it's something I keep getting caught on :(  The other option is to have a ModelState.Clear(); call in your controller action.

Comment: Anybody have any idea on why it was designed this way, if it's not a bug?

Comment: OK the link is gone forever :( . By the way, in case you don't want to clear the modelstate, removing the problematic key worked for me: `ModelState.Remove("HiddenKey")`

Answer (score 5):

To add to Manaf's correct answer--you note correctly that the problem occurs in controller actions that handle posts.  I was getting the same problem in a controller action that handles a get when I explicitly pass a model to a view:

```
[HttpGet]
ActionResult SearchForSomething(SearchForm searchForm)
{
    searchForm.MyId = SomeValueFromSession;
    return View("SearchForSomething", searchForm);
}
```

In the view, this line that rendered a hidden input for MyId always rendered "0":

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyId);
```

Per Darren Oster's suggestion I changed to the following and fixed the problem:

```
[HttpGet]
ActionResult SearchForSomething(SearchForm searchForm)
{
    searchForm.MyId = SomeValueFromSession;
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View("SearchForSomething", searchForm);
}
```

Comment: Both the normal <input> tag and ModelState.Clear() work for me, but I find it clearer to use the latter (with the proper comment ofr my followers) than mixing @Html.xxx and input tags in my views...

Answer (score 0):

My comment is relegated to the last place (even I couldn't find it), so:

In case you don't want to clear the modelstate, as Darren Oster suggested, removing the problematic key worked for me: `ModelState.Remove("HiddenKey")`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well with @Html.HiddenFor.

@Html.Hidden("Id", Model.Id) also gave value 0, but a foreign key field, e.g., @Html.Hidden("Model_Category_ModelId", Model.Category.ModelId) did work, while it @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Category.ModelId) did not.

My solution was to redirect to the get action, as described in [ASP NET MVC Post Redirect Get Pattern](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2011/04/asp-net-mvc-post-redirect-get-pattern/).