# MVC3 Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Id) not passing back to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, view, controller, html-helper

I have created a strongly typed MVC3 Razor view using the scaffolding code.

The model is a POCO with a base type of `PersistentEntity` which defines a property called Created, Updated and Id.

Id is an int, Created and Updated are DateTime.

I am using `Html.HiddenFor` to create the hidden field on the view.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Created)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Updated)
```

On the page, the hidden input is being rendered properly, with the Id being set in the value.

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="12">
```

However when the page is submitted to the controller `[HttpPost]Edit(Model model)` the Id property is always 0. Created and Updated are correctly populated with the values from the View.

[image]

This should be 12 in the case of the example in this post. What is going wrong?

---

I am aware that I can change the method signature to `[HttpPost]Edit(int personID, Person model)` as the personID is in the get string, however why does the model not get populated with the hidden field?

---

**Update**

The problem was that the setter on `PersistentEntity` was protected, ASP could not set the property, and swallowed it. Changing this to public has solved the problem.

```
public abstract class PersistentEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Updated { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This should work. Have you checked the contructor and the property setter for Id in your class?

Comment: It works for me, so we're missing something that is not mentioned in question - custom binders, custom javascript form submit, something like that...

Comment: How does the model class containing the Id property look like?

Comment: I think you are right - the Id setter is protected. ASP MVC was swallowing the fact that it could not set the `Id`. Changing to a non protected setter solved the problem.

Comment: @Macropus Thank you for the update that you added to your question. That gave me a clue where to look for in my case. It's a little unfortunate that by the looks of it programming by convention doesn't necessarily give you a lot of traces info, exception, etc. to tell you want you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
```

`protected set;` `<!--` That's your problem. You need a **public setter** if you want the default model binder to be able to assign the value.

Comment: If you're looking at this post and you already have a public setter on your POCO, you may find this post useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606087/why-mvc-html-hiddenfor-does-not-render-my-field