# I am having trouble with a html helper, why is it not working?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

I have a viewModel that has a field called COESNo..

when I try to write it in the view like so

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.COESNo)
```

and then try to access it later using Jquery  $("#COESNo).val() it says it is empty

but if I do the following

```
 <input type="hidden" id="COESNo" value="@Model.COESNo" />
```

I can get the value from Jquery.. why is it setting the value to empty when I use the hiddenfor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so finally worked out what the issue was.  The request was a Get request and there was a query string value called 'COESNo'.  This seem to confuse the Hiddenfor.  I changed the variable name to COESValue and it works a treat.  Is it trying to model bind in the razor view?

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the source of the page, specifically the id attribute of the hidden field generated by  @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.COESNo). If this line is inside of a partial view (that is, the partial's model is a subset of the main model), or is inside of a loop, the id attribute's value will have a prefix. You will then need to take this prefix into account in your jQuery selector.

Comment: this is what is in the source    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field COESNo must be a number." data-val-required="The COESNo field is required." id="COESNo" name="COESNo" type="hidden" value="" />

Comment: The selector should work then. One small thing that I've noticed is that in the statement $("#COESNo).val() you don't have closing quote. Is that just a typo or it's like that in your actual code?

Comment: just a typo.... but if you see the hidden field above, the value is set to nothing...

Comment: if I use <input type="hidden" id="COESNo" value="@Model.COESNo" />  then the source becomes <input type="hidden" id="COESNo" value="13054915" />.. no other changes at all

Comment: Look at this post, is this relevant to your situation? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606087/why-mvc-html-hiddenfor-does-not-render-my-field/3607188#3607188

Comment: m1kael - not the case with me, Nothing to do with a post, its a GET, and when the viewmodel is getting populated I can see the value for COESNO, I can see it even in Razor page (debugging and inspecting the @Model)