# Html.HiddenFor outputs blank value first time and correct value if repeated

Tags: model-view-controller, html.hiddenfor

I'm using MVC 2. When I do this:

```
      <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SourceType) %>
```

I get this in the view:

```
      <input id="SourceType" type="hidden" value="" name="SourceType">
```

I confirmed that the model has the correct value before returning the view in the controller. The value is correctly set to 11.

I started trying different things to see if I could get any different result and found that if I repeat the textbox like this:

```
      <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SourceType) %>
      <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SourceType) %>
```

Results in this:

```
      <input id="SourceType" type="hidden" value="" name="SourceType">
      <input id="SourceType" type="hidden" value="11" name="SourceType">
```

Can anyone think of a reason why the view is rendering the first textbox with a blank value while the second contains the correct value?

EDIT: I thought this might be caused by javascript so I removed all scripts from the page, but the value is still blank the first time and correct when repeated.

EDIT: Based on jle's link I tried this:

```
      <input type="hidden" value="<%= Html.AttributeEncode(Model.SourceType) %>" id="SourceType" name="SourceType" />
      <input id="SourceType" type="hidden" value="11" name="SourceType">
      <input id="SourceType" type="hidden" value="11" name="SourceType">
```

And got this:

```
      <input id="SourceType" type="hidden" name="SourceType" value="">
      <input id="SourceType" type="hidden" value="11" name="SourceType">
      <input id="SourceType" type="hidden" value="11" name="SourceType">
```

Also, based on the link I tried this in the controller just before returning the view:

```
      ModelState.Clear();
```

Result is still the same. The first value to be rendered is blank.

EDIT: Here is the controller code:

```
      Source source = SourceService.NewSource();
      return View("Source", Mapper.Map(source, new SourceViewModel()));
```

EDIT: Problem seems isolated to the use of HiddenFor helper.

I did this:

```
      <%: Model.SourceType %>
      <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SourceType) %>
      <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SourceType) %>
```

And got this:

```
      11
      <input id="SourceType" type="hidden" value="" name="SourceType">
      <input id="SourceType" type="hidden" value="11" name="SourceType">
```

EDIT: Following jle's input I tried this but still no luck:

```
      <input id="SourceType" type="hidden" value="<%: Model.SourceType %>" name="SourceType">
      <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SourceType) %>
      <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SourceType) %>
```

This results in this:

```
      <input id="SourceType" type="hidden" name="SourceType" value="">
      <input id="SourceType" type="hidden" value="11" name="SourceType">
      <input id="SourceType" type="hidden" value="11" name="SourceType">
```

EDIT: If I exclude the name when not using the helper and used type="text" instead of type="hidden". This renders the value, but doesn't post because it is missing the name (I think).

This:

```
      <input id="SourceType" type="text" value="<%: Model.SourceType %>" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
```

Results in this which doesn't bind to the model when posted? How can adding the name affect the value?

```
      <input id="SourceType" type="text" style="visibility: hidden;" value="11">
```

EDIT: If anyone can think of something to try I'd love to hear it. I've resorted to an ugly work around involving the addition of a stand in property on the view model. This allows me to set the stand in property value in the controller which renders as expected on the page. On post then I have to manually map the property back the SourceType property. Ugh...

Comment: What is datattype of sourcetype?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606087/why-mvc-html-hiddenfor-does-not-render-my-field

Comment: Thanks for the link jle. I edited the post. Still no luck.

Comment: Where is value set in your controller?  Can you add controller code?

Comment: The controller gets the model from the service layer, then using AutoMapper, maps it to a view model. I updated the post with the return statement that accomplished this.

Comment: @user3731057 Did you ever solve this? Seeing something similar...

Comment: Actually, I solved it 2 seconds later. :) In my case, I had a querystring parameter (whose value was empty) by the same name as my model's property which I was trying to render to a hidden input. So, it was using the querystring parameter instead of the model's property value.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have an empty querystring parameter by the same property name. `HiddenFor` appears to prefer what's in the querystring over what's in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ModelState.Remove("SourceType"); in the controller:

```
ModelState.Remove("SourceType");
Source source = SourceService.NewSource();
return View("Source", Mapper.Map(source, new SourceViewModel()));
```

If there is already a value in the ModelState that corresponds to your value, it will use that first.  Alternatively, I would double check that the value is mapping correctly to the ViewModel.  When you say you checked this, did you check the model itself or just the Source property?

Edit:
Try `<input id="SourceType" type="hidden" value="<%: Model.SourceType %>" name="SourceType">`

Comment: ModelState.Remove("SourceType") didn't change the result. The first rendering is blank. Also I checked the model itself while debugging. Finally, I think you're on the right track. The problem seems isolated to the hiddenfor helper. See edits on post.

Comment: Thanks again jle, but still no luck. I added <input id="SourceType" type="hidden" value="<%: Model.SourceType %>" name="SourceType"> but it is still blank. I updated the post as well

Comment: jle, while I'm not setting SourceType in the controller I am putting several things in ViewData. None of them are named SourceType, but could this be affecting the result? Sorry... grasping at straws here...